# R - Use time to restrict size of group

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, rcpp, cumsum

I have a very large dataset that is indexed by time.  I'd like to group messages together by time, where the first message (at time T) starts a group, that group persists until time T+X, at which point a new group is started.  The dataset can have large gaps (>X) between observations

Example where the maximum group size (X, above) is 2 time ticks.  The column "group" is the desired output:

```
> example=data.table(time=c(1,2,3,4,8,13,14,17), 
group=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5))
> example
   time group
1:    1     1
2:    2     1
3:    3     2
4:    4     2
5:    8     3
6:   13     4
7:   14     4
8:   17     5
```

Another example when X=7

```
> example2=data.table(time=c(43,44,75,76,77,80,81,82,83,84), group=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3))
> example2
    time group
 1:   43     1
 2:   44     1
 3:   75     2
 4:   76     2
 5:   77     2
 6:   80     2
 7:   81     2
 8:   82     3
 9:   83     3
10:   84     3
```

One way Ive thought about doing this is calculating the diff between the times and using a cumsum function which resets to zero after it reaches the threshold (2 in this case), but I havent been able to figure out how to achieve that reset.  I'm worried that my only solution here will end up being iterative (and as a result, too slow for R by itself).

---Edit with some examples of what I've tried more specifically
First calculating the cumsum of the time deltas

```
> example[,cumulativeTime:=cumsum(c(0,diff(time)))]
> example
   time group timeDiff cumulativeTime
1:    1     1       NA              0
2:    2     1        1              1
3:    3     2        1              2
4:    4     2        1              3
5:    8     3        4              7
6:   13     4        5             12
7:   14     4        1             13
8:   17     5        3             16
```

Then considered taking the modulo of the cumulative time by the max number of time ticks, with the thought that when the deltas between subsequent modulos is < 0, that would indicate a new group, however as you can see that breaks down when there is any meaningful gap in the data.

```
> example[,cumTimeMod := cumulativeTime %% 2]
> example
   time group timeDiff cumulativeTime cumTimeMod
1:    1     1       NA              0           0
2:    2     1        1              1           1
3:    3     2        1              2           0
4:    4     2        1              3           1
5:    8     3        4              7           1
6:   13     4        5             12           0
7:   14     4        1             13           1
8:   17     5        3             16           0
```

Additionally, also tried integer division rather than modulo which also failed.  Different example, where X=7 (also incorporated mt1022's suggestion below):

```
    time timeDiff cumulativeTime intDivOfCsumByX desiredGroup g1 g2 g
 1:   43        0              0               0            1  0  1 1
 2:   44        1              1               0            1  0  1 1
 3:   75       31             32               4            2 30  1 2
 4:   76        1             33               4            2 30  1 2
 5:   77        1             34               4            2 30  1 2
 6:   80        3             37               5            2 32  1 3
 7:   81        1             38               5            2 32  1 3
 8:   82        1             39               5            3 32  1 3
 9:   83        1             40               5            3 32  1 3
10:   84        1             41               5            3 32  1 3
```

Comment: Please show what you have attempted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with an Rcpp approach to overcome the slowness with R+iterative algorithms

```
cpp.cumsumgrp = cppFunction('
NumericVector cumsumgrp(NumericVector x, int resetMax) {
int n = x.size();
NumericVector tmp(n);
NumericVector res(n);
tmp[0]=0;
long groupCount=0;
for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
    long csum=tmp[i-1]+x[i];
    if(csum > resetMax) {
      groupCount++;
    }
    tmp[i] = csum > resetMax ? 0 : csum;
    res[i] = groupCount;

}
return(res);
}');
```

Usage (x-1 to account for inclusive/exclusive max cumsum.  I also dont care about the actual numeric value of the group ID, only that all messages in the same group have the same ID):

```
> x=7
> example2[,assignedGroup:=cumsumgrp(c(0,diff(time)), x-1)]
> example2
    time desiredGroup assignedGroup
 1:   43            1             0
 2:   44            1             0
 3:   75            2             1
 4:   76            2             1
 5:   77            2             1
 6:   80            2             1
 7:   81            2             1
 8:   82            3             2
 9:   83            3             2
10:   84            3             2
```

Comment: If you could make a benchmark with a big example, that'd be cool.

Comment: Hm, also you should add how this is to be used. `example[, cpp.cumsumgrp(time, 2L)]` gives the wrong result.

Comment: Added usage.  Apologies, forgot to explicitly call out that this uses the time delta for the cumsum rather than the time directly.  You could easily modify the C++ to calculate the time delta for you and then eliminate the need for the explicit diff() call

Comment: After far as benchmarks go, my anecdotal results were that the iterative solution in the other answer took >5min for 10M rows.  The Rcpp version returns nearly instantly.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. My guess is that doing the rolling join with data.table and the loop in cpp would be fastest, but to write that I'd need to study up on cpp (e.g., to find a growable vector data structure to traverse the `nxts`). It's also possible that `v <-
 f(time, 7L); rep(seq_along(v), diff(c(v, .N))` or a rolling join would be faster than `cumsum(.I %in% f(time, 7L))` but without something to benchmark against, I won't look into it further.